# Java JPanel .updateUI() removes my setBound data

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm having a problem when i use .updateUI() in my JPanels, The bounds i set return to default.

```
    //Set my Frame
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1600,900);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    //Set Panel
    JPanel menuInput = new JPanel();
    menuInput.setBounds(100,100,500,500);

    //Set Button
    JButton buttonSolve = new JButton();
    buttonSolve.setBounds(30,30,400,200);

    menuInput .add(buttonSolve);
    frame.add(menuInput);
    //If i updateUI, the bound returns to default.
    menuInput.updateUI();
```

However if i place my  menuInput.updateUI before frame.add(menuInput) it will not affect the bounds, but i need to refresh my Panel every time new data comes in.

Comment: Using a null layout and setBounds is not a good idea.  [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) were designed to layout Swing components in a JPanel container.  I've never had to call the updateUI method.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I use MigLayout, and i have no problem with setting the positions of each object now.